# "sls dynamodb start" throws spawn java ENOENT

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

running on Mac, I've created a basic serverless service using the aws-nodejs template:

```
serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path TestService
```

After that I used the following commands to add serverless local:

```
npm install serverless-dynamodb-local
serverless dynamodb install
```

No matter what I do, I can't get dynamodb-local to start. When I run

```
serverless dynamodb start
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: spawn java ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Running `java --version` gives me the following info:

```
Java 10.0.2 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

I'm using Node 8.11.4 with serverless 1.30.1. Aws-sdk is also installed and I've setup my profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug with version **serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.31**.

[issue on github](https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/181)

I've downgraded to version 0.2.30 by using

```
npm uninstall serverless-dynamodb-local
sls dynamodb uninstall

npm install serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.30
sls dynamodb install
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Missed this among all the issues on Github: /

Comment: Tried a bunch of solutions, but only this one worked. Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully that plugin gets updated soon.  This was hard to find a fix for.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I have had `^0.2.35` installed with no problems until today. Turns out `0.2.36` was just released and has the same problem. I am staying on `0.2.35` for the time being and removed the carrot in my `package.json`

Comment: I was on `0.2.38` and saw this problem, downgrading to `0.2.37` fixed it...

Answer (score 5):

Following the advice on [serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/195](https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/195#issuecomment-455587789),  I just ran `sls dynamodb install --localPath ./bin` and Dynamodb installed correctly. Running `serverless offline start` then worked without error.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: Oh man, I was getting worried. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed jre to run dynamodb jar. Otherwise this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to go with "serverless-dynamodb" instead of "serverless-dynamodb-local". Actually that's a fork from dynamodb-local only. Here is the documentation for migrating it.

> https://github.com/raisenational/serverless-dynamodb#migrating-from-serverless-dynamodb-local

You need java installed in your system in both of the case.
Use this command if you're a ubuntu user for installing java.

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Need to setup java home env variable as well.